# Grpc Server not defined

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, grpc

In my attempt to send an image over Grpc in c# .Net6, I have encountered an issue with the ImageSender.cs file. Specifically, an error message is being displayed indicating that the server is undefined. After some investigation, I have come to suspect that the root of the problem may lie in the first line of the Programm.cs file:
`using imageservice.Services;` 
here is the code:

.proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "ImageService";
package imageservice;


message ImageChunk {
  bytes data = 1;
}

message ImageRequest {
  string id = 1;
}

service ImageService {
  rpc SendImage (ImageRequest) returns (stream ImageChunk);
}
```

ImageSender.cs

```
using Grpc.Core;
using ImageService;



class ImageSender
{
    const int Port = 50051;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Server server = new Server
        {
            Services = { ImageService.ImageService.BindService(new ImageServiceImpl()) },
            Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
        };

        server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine($"ImageService server listening on port {Port}");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
    }
}

public class ImageServiceImpl : ImageService.ImageService.ImageServiceBase
{
    public override async Task SendImage(ImageRequest request, IServerStreamWriter<ImageChunk> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var imagePath = $"./images/{request.Id}.jpg";

        if (File.Exists(imagePath))
        {
            using FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            const int chunkSize = 64 * 1024; // 64 KB
            byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
            {
                await responseStream.WriteAsync(new ImageChunk { Data = ByteString.CopyFrom(buffer, 0, bytesRead) });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.NotFound, $"Image with id {request.Id} not found."));
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using imageservice.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
// For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddGrpc();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<I>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

app.Run();
```

I get the following erros:

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'imageservice' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  GrpcImageServer C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\GrpcImageServer\GrpcImageServer\Program.cs    1   Active
```

and

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Server' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    GrpcImageServer C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\GrpcImageServer\GrpcImageServer\Services\ImageSender.cs   12  Active
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the error message? Please copy paste it directly, and specify which line it refers to. It's not clear to me why you've got `using imageservice.Services` when you're specifying a namespace of `ImageService` elsewhere... why don't you just have `using ImageService;`?

Comment: Read the RED item in the link you provided especially the PORT NUMBER.

Comment: I get the following erros:

```Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'imageservice' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) GrpcImageServer C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\GrpcImageServer\GrpcImageServer\Program.cs 1 Active```

and ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Server' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) GrpcImageServer C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\GrpcImageServer\GrpcImageServer\Services\ImageSender.cs 12 Active```

Comment: After modifying the ASP .NET Core gRPC service template in Visual Studio 22, I am uncertain as to which using directive should be included in the Program.cs file.

Comment: Please edit the question to include all the details there, rather than putting important information just in comments. But fundamentally, do you understand what a using directive does, and do you know which namespace you want to import? Note that you've got two separate errors here, as far as I can see. Try to tackle them separately.

Comment: Yes, i understand using directives, just my understanding of gRPC is lacking.

I am pretty sure, that the second is caused by the first, since the part missing in the second is autogenerated by gRPC. The part i am uncertain about is which namespace to import.

Comment: The reason why jon said you don't understand "using" is because in order to fix these errors you would need to understand that "using" references external objects and code.  It seems to me that you don't know what code that is to create the imageservice and server objects.  We don't know either.  What external code are you expecting to use?